# Making a menu inside a menu

Tags: c

I am trying to make a menu within a menu.
My problem is that the value of "choice" is not changed and thus the program stops when I am trying to change the value of choice, e.g. when I entered (2) as my first choice, then I enter (0), and when I enter (1), the program just terminates.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int choice, choiceJR;

void mainMenu() {
  printf("Select one of the following. \n");  
  printf("1. x \n");
  printf("2. menuJR \n");
  printf("3. xxx \n");

  printf("Choice: \n");
  scanf("%d", &choice);
}

void menuJR() {
  printf("Select one of the following. \n");
  printf("1. y \n");
  printf("2. yy \n");
  printf("0. go back \n");

  printf("Choice: \n");
  scanf("%d", &choiceJR);

}

int main() {

  mainMenu();

  while(choice != 1 && choice!= 2 && choice!= 3) {
    printf("Invalid choice! \n");
    mainMenu();
  }
  if(choice == 1) {
    printf("You have selected 1 \n");
  }
  else if(choice == 2) {
    printf("You have selected 2 \n");
    menuJR();
    while(choiceJR != 0) {
      menuJR();
    }
    if(choiceJR == 0) {
      printf("Going to menu! \n");
      mainMenu();
    }
  }
  else if(choice == 3) {
    printf("You have selected 3 \n");
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use `state machine` rather `if...else`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should use do_while loop for choosing items.
- Here is your solution, use this code.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int choiceJR=0;

  int mainMenu() {
      int choice=0;
      printf("Select one of the following. \n");  
      printf("1. x \n");
      printf("2. menuJR \n");
      printf("3. xxx \n");

      printf("Choice: \n");
      scanf("%d", &choice);
      return choice;
  }

  void menuJR() {
      printf("Select one of the following. \n");
      printf("1. y \n");
      printf("2. yy \n");
      printf("0. go back \n");

      scanf("%d", &choiceJR);
  }

  int main() {
      int ch=0;

      do {
          main:
          ch = mainMenu();
          while(ch != 1 && ch!= 2 && ch!= 3) {
              printf("Invalid choice! \n");
              mainMenu(ch);
          }

          switch(ch) {
              case 1:
                  printf("You have selected 1 \n");
                  break;

              case 2:
                  printf("You have selected 2 \n");
                  menuJR();
                  while(choiceJR != 0) {
                      menuJR();
                  }
                  if(choiceJR == 0) {
                      printf("Going to menu! \n");
                      goto main;
                  }
                  break;

              case 3:
                  printf("You have selected 3 \n");
                  break;

              default: 
                  printf("invalid choice \n");
          }

      }
      while(ch<=3);

      return 0;
  }
  ```